# internet access on natted server

Tags: ssh, internet, vpn, firewall, nat

I have two linux servers say X and Y. There is a VPN connectivity between the two, such that X can connect Y through some ports(e.g. 22,5901 etc) but Y can not connect X. internet is available on X.

I want to access internet on server Y. How can I do that?

Comment: If there is VPN connectivity, surely machine Y must already have Internet connectivity and its a matter of firewalling ?

Comment: I want to use internet of X on Y using tunneling/proxy.
A simple list of commands will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is non-trivial and you have not provided anything like enough details for an exact solution, but, in general terms the steps you need to take are:

1. Set up a default gateway on Y through X, without breaking the VPN connection. This is
   probably a matter of adding a specific route for the VPN endpoint/subnet, and changing
   the default gateway on X.
2. The firewall (if one exists) on Y needs to be modified to allow traffic to and from X.
3. packet forwarding needs to be enabled on (echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward) 
   should generally work.
4. You need to set up masquerading / NAT on server Y to rewrite the packets leaving it.
   This will depend on your interfaces, but something like
   /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o (Ext IF on Y, eg eth0) -j MASQUERADE 
   will usually work.
5. You may need to add MTU clamping if some sites work but others don't.
   Something like 
   iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu

Note that depending on your Internet requirements you might not actually need any of this - you may be able to use SSH to create a SOCKS proxy and simply use that (but that will only work if the Internet clients you are using on X support SOCKS).  This is an order of magnitude easier to do for a one off if you can get away with it though.